# React Native Expo Notifications not showing in foreground

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo

I am developing an Expo React Native application, and now I am implementing Expo Notifications. The notifications works as expected when the app is in the background, but when the app is in the foreground, nothing appears.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync()
      .then((token) => {
        console.log("token: ", token);
        if (customUser && token && customUser.expoPushToken !== token) {
          updateExpoPushToken(customUser.userId, token)
            .then((action) => {
              if (action) {
                dispatch(action);
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error registering for push notifications: ", error);
      });

    Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
      handleNotification: async () => ({
        shouldShowAlert: true,
        shouldPlaySound: true,
        shouldSetBadge: true,
      }),
    });

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        setNotification(notification);
        console.log(
          "notification received: " + notification.request.content.body
        );
      });

    return () => {
      if (notificationListener.current) {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
      }
      if (responseListener.current) {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
      }
    };
  }, [Notifications]);
```

The addNotificationReceivedListener does not fire at all when the app is in the foreground. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

UPDATE:
The notifications worked fine in the foreground during earlier development, so I went back to the earlier commits to see where the error started. I noticed that I changed the expo.owner-field in my app.json file to the name of my expo-organization in order to share the app with external users. This was the source of the error, and when I changed the expo.owner field back to original, it is no longer an issue. But now I don't know how to share the app with other people..